# How to create an array in jQuery for holding values of each post?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is set an icon for each category using jQuery. So far the code looks like this:

```
var category = $(".odd, .even").children('.views-field-field-category').text();

if (category=="funny") { 
   $(".odd, .even").children('.views-field-field-category').html('image-tag'); 
}
```

Since the variable category gathers all of the category values in that page and combines them (so that it looks like "funny gifs videos gifs" etc) I've decided that I need an array to hold them each seperately. Now I've tried to do it in various ways, but without any success. Can you please help and show me how to set it up so that I could use `if (category[i]=="funny") { do this }`?

Comment: Can you show a representative sample of your HTML, and explain what should happen, and what you want?

Comment: @Xeen how would you determine `i` in `category[i]`?

Comment: `<td class="views-field views-field-field-category"><a href="/cat/funny">Funny</a></td>` for reasons too complicated for me [since I'm trying to do this using drupal and I'm a complete newb at the thing], I cannot just use an icon in the anchor tag which is why I'm trying to achieve the desired effect with jQuery.

Comment: `i` in `category[i]` was supposed to be a variable coming from a loop so that it would check each value of an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object:

```
var o = {
   'funny' : 'html-tag',
   'gifs'  : 'html-tag2',
   'crazy' : '...'
}
```

And use `html` callback function.

```
$(".odd, .even").children('.views-field-field-category').html(function(i, html){
   var prop = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
   return o[prop];
})
```

Comment: I know it wasn't specified based on the original question, but I always like to use `toLowerCase()` when I am indexing an array by text just to be safe.

Comment: @scott.korin Yes, this is a good suggestion, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that isn't working for me either.